# ASP.NET Membership: safe user delete

Tags: asp.net, membership

I am the administrator and I need to delete a user.

If the user is authenticated at the moment I delete it, what is the best strategy to force the deleted user to logout at the next request?

Must I handle this operation in the `Application_AuthenticateRequest` event?

In other words, can be an idea to verify in the `AuthenticateRequest` event if the user still exists and, if not, to delete all the cookies and redirect to logon page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research and evaluation, finally I have found a strategy to handle this scenario, so, in Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest()
{
    var user = HttpContext.Current.User;
    if (user != null)
    {
        if (Membership.GetUser(user.Identity.Name, true) == null)
        {
            CookieHelper.Clear();
            Response.RedirectToRoute("Login");
        }
    }
}
```

When the request is authenticated, we verify that the user still exists in the system, if not all the cookies will be deleted and the request will be redirected to the login page.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete them, then I'm assuming their next request would most likely error out for them.

Even if they have the authentication cookie, any page that checks the database against their UserID would obviously throw an exception.

You can most likely just disable the user instead of having to delete them.

Comment: Ok. I must surely disable the user. But how to manage the "delete user scenario"? Can be an idea to verify in the Application_AuthenticatedRequest event if the user already exist and if not to delete all cookies and redirect to logon?

Comment: Yeah, the application will probably just error out if they're deleted while using.  In that case, what's the difference between seeing an error or the login page; they're no longer a user either way.

Comment: The difference is that if I manage properly the situation I can delete all the cookies and the next visit to the site will be safe from errors.

Comment: Oh, I never considered the possibility that you'd want them to come back.